# Reading MS excel file from C++

Tags: c++, excel, libraries

I'm looking for a way to open an excel spreadsheet and read data from it within a c++ program. I know there is a lot of question already asked about this, but I would like to use an OpenSource or free library. (not duplicate question! + Googled around and nothing found)

Thanks

Comment: @Mr E: now looks better? I don't know English well...

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to be snarky. The word you wanted was "programmatically". "Problematically" means something else!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ library to load Excel (.xls) files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876720/c-library-to-load-excel-xls-files)

Comment: This question asks for a free C++ library that can be used to load MS Excel files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876720/c-library-to-load-excel-xls-files In that way is that not an exact duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned over in [Article 2876720](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876720/c-library-to-load-excel-xls-files), [ExcelFormat](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42504/ExcelFormat-Library) fits the bill.  I have used it with success.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will do the trick for you: [XLW - A Wrapper for the Excel API](http://xlw.sourceforge.net/)